# Making radiometric calibration on Planet Image?

Tags: planet

How can make radiometric calibration on Planet Image? I tried to on ENVI, but I did not succeed. Cause software need gain and offset value for every band. But I did not find this value. Do you have any solution this matter?

Comment: What product are you using and what product level is it? I am fairly sure that most of them are radiometrically corrected prior to release.

Comment: 20180827_073128_104b_3B_AnalyticMS.tif,yes but i need reflectance value.So i want  to convert  reflectance,but i didn't.

Comment: The coefficient values can be found in the metadata file. I am not sure if ENVI can handle this. Planet's 3B products do sometimes come as either TOA radiance or surface reflectance so you may be able to choose when you download?

Comment: If you know Python you can achieve what you are looking for with this https://developers.planet.com/tutorials/convert-planetscope-imagery-from-radiance-to-reflectance/